# Brute force a zip file with python 2

Tags: python-2.7, zip

I need to open a zip and extract the contents. The password starts with "Super" and has three letters after it.
I have already got most of the code but its not working properly.
Can anyone see the error because it doesn't actually show an error it just doesn't work.

```
import zipfile
import itertools
import time

# Function for extracting zip files to test if the password works!
def extractFile(zip_file, password):
    try:
        zip_file.extractall(pwd=password)
        return True
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit(0)
    except Exception, e:
        pass

# Main code starts here...
# The file name of the zip file.
zipfilename = 'planz.zip'
# The first part of the password. We know this for sure!
first_half_password = 'Super'
# We don't know what characters they add afterwards...
# This is case sensitive!
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename)

# We know they always have 3 characters after Super...
# For every possible combination of 3 letters from alphabet...
for c in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=3):
    # Slowing it down on purpose to make it work better with the web terminal
    # Remove at your peril
    #time.sleep(0.001)
    # Add the three letters to the first half of the password.
    password = first_half_password+''.join(c)
    # Try to extract the file.
    print "Trying: %s" % password
    extractFile(zip_file, password)
    # If the file was extracted, you found the right password.
    if extractFile(zip_file, password):
        print '*' * 20
        print 'Password found: %s' % password
        print 'Files extracted...'
        exit(0)
        break

# If no password was found by the end, let us know!
print 'Password not found.'
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you're cheating at cyberstart, but regardless:
Your alphabet is missing some characters. What if the password had capital letters, or numbers, or punctuation?

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

That should do it